# Java String toString method null error

Tags: java

Please I am trying to get the items of an order, the items are coffee muffin and timBits, by using the method

public String toString()

Every thing is working properly except that I do not get the items of the order I get null for them instead of the following:

```
    Muffin   "Bran"              ,3
    Coffee   "Latte"             , 1
    TimBits  "Assorted"         , 24
    Muffin   "Chocolate"        , 1
    Coffee   "Decaf"            , 2
   TimBits   "Chocolate"        , 12
   Muffin    "PeanutButter"     , 2
   Muffin    "Blueberry"        , 5
```

the numbers above represents the quantity of each item in the order.

```
class Item
{
  protected String description;
  protected int quantity;
  protected String kind;
  private double cost;

   public double getCost()
   {
      return this.cost;
   }

 public Item (String description, int quantity)
 {
   this.description = description;
   this.quantity = quantity;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
   return "Item: " + "      " +kind + "      " + ": description: "  + "      " +description  +"quantity:" +"        " + quantity ;

 }

 class Coffee extends Item
{
  protected double cost1Coffee;
  String kind = "Coffee";
  public Coffee (String description, int quantity)


 {
   super(description, quantity);
   cost1Coffee = 4 ;
 }

 }
}


 class Muffin extends Item
{
  protected double cost1Muffin;
  protected double cost2Muffin;
  protected double cost3Muffin;
  String kind = "Muffin";
  public Muffin (String description, int quantity)

 {
   super(description,quantity);
   cost1Muffin = 1;
   cost2Muffin = 0.75;
   cost3Muffin = 0.50;
 }



}


 class TimBits extends Item
{
 protected double  cost1TimBits ;
 String kind = "TimBits";
 public TimBits (String description, int quantity)

 {
   super(description, quantity);
   cost1TimBits = 0.25;
 }

}



/***************************************************************/
/***************************************************************/

class A4Q1Util
{
 private static ArrayList<Item> order;

 private static int count = 0;

 public static Item getItem()
 {
  Item item;

  if (order==null)
  {
   order = new ArrayList<Item>();

   order.add(new Muffin("Bran", 3));
   order.add(new Coffee("Latte", 1));
   order.add(new TimBits("Assorted", 24));
   order.add(new Muffin("Chocolate", 1));
   order.add(new Coffee("Decaf", 2));
   order.add(new TimBits("Chocolate", 12));
   order.add(new Muffin("PeanutButter", 2));
   order.add(new Muffin("Blueberry", 5));
  }

  item = null;
  if (count<order.size())
  {
   item = order.get(count);
   count++;
  }
  {
  return item;
  }


 }
}



output:

Item:       null      : description:       Branquantity:        3 
Item:       null      : description:       Lattequantity:        1 
Item:       null      : description:       Assortedquantity:        24 
Item:       null      : description:       Chocolatequantity:        1 
Item:       null      : description:       Decafquantity:        2 
Item:       null      : description:       Chocolatequantity:        12 
Item:       null      : description:       PeanutButterquantity:        2 
Item:       null      : description:       Blueberryquantity:        5 

Program completed normally.
```

> 

Comment: If your question is answered, accept the appropriate answer, do not remove your quesiton from the site!

Answer (score 4):

Don't declare the field `kind` in every sub-class. Add the assignment to the constructors, e.g.:

```
public TimBits (String description, int quantity) {
    super(description, quantity);
    kind = "TimBits";
    cost1TimBits = 0.25;
}
```

Comment: Actually, why isn't the current solution working? That is, what's wrong with assigning `kind` outside of the constructor.

Comment: @Keikoku that's called hiding of fields. I've updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: @Keikoku Because the compiler will use the "first match". Declaring the variable in the child class will "hide" the original field in the child class and assignments to `kind` will therefore be made to the sub-class field, not the super-class field.

Comment: The `toString()` is inherited by the children and therefore wouldn't it be the case that  when a child calls `toString()` it'll grab its own `kind`?

Comment: @Keikoku No, because `toString()` is still a method of `Item` and therefore accesses the field of the class `Item`. If you wrote the same method again in each of the child classes, you'd get the output you expect.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Item#toString` method:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Item: " + "      " +kind + "      " + ": description: "  + "      " +description  +"quantity:" +"        " + quantity ;
}
```

You use `kind` variable, but never initialize it through your application.

This is because you're [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) the `kind` field on every child class. Instead, declare it as `protected` in parent class and just initialize it accordingly on each child.

```
class Coffee extends Item {
    protected double cost1Coffee;
    //drop this
    //String kind = "Coffee";
    public Coffee(...) {
        super(...);
        kind = "Coffee";
    }
}
```

You can even be more restrictive about the `kind` field by marking it as `final` and disallowing any other class modifying it except its children when executing the constructor. A sample of this:

```
class Item {
    //other fields...
    protected final String kind;
    protected Item (String description, int quantity, String kind) {
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.kind = kind;
    }
    public Item (String description, int quantity) {
        this(description, quantity, "uncategorized");
    }
}

class Coffee extends Item {
    public Coffee(String description, int quantity) {
        //similar in other subclasses of Item
        super(description, quantity, "Coffee");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to `String kind` inside each subclass of `Item`. However, this `kind` is not the same as the `kind` field of the superclass `Item` since the subclass field masks that of the superclass. You have two options to fix this.

1. Expand the `Item` constructor to accept a `String kind` and add to the call to `super`.

   ```
    super(description,quantity,"Muffin");
   ```
2. Assign to `kind` inside the subclass constructors so that the correct `kind` is assigned to (the one declared in `Item` which is used by `toString()`).

   ```
    public Muffin (String description, int quantity)
    {
       kind = "Muffin";
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never initialize your variable `kind` and even though you are extending from the superclass "Item" throughout all of your child classes, you're simply overloading the variable name `kind` and redefining it. Therefore when you make the call to the toString() method, your parent class (Item) never gets it's `kind` variable initialized. What you need to do is also set the `kind` in the constructor so that you can pass it in through super().